# Is there any GOOD reason why I can't use "script" tags without any attributes?

Tags: html

In most of the HTML apps I can get away with:

```
<script>
    // my code
</script>
```

(in fact, even Stackoverflow.com uses the above notation).

But technical, the more correct way is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // my code
</script>
```

So, does it really make a difference which one I use, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `type`-attribute in `script`-tags is optional, if you're using HTML5.

> The `type` attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME type. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "`text/javascript`".

Source: [The World Wide Web Consortium](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type).

Conclusion:
If you're working with HTML5, it's not wrong to declare the `type`, but it's not necessary, if you're using javascript. In other Versions of HTML it's still mandatory.

Comment: +1 for linking w3c instead of w3schools, htmldoctor or any other unofficial source

Answer (score 1):

The type attribute is optional and defaults to text/javascript. So no, you don't need it, and it's not "more correct" to include it. (This applies to HTML5).

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 there's no need to include a type attribute for  and  tags.

http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/#type-attr